# Discord Game SDK library for x86 and x64 in one directory

Tags: c++, discord

I connect the Discord Game SDK Library for my c++ game and it compiles on the

x64 and win32 architecture.

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma comment(lib, "lib/x86_64/discord_game_sdk.dll.lib")
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#pragma comment(lib, "lib/x86/discord_game_sdk.dll.lib")
#endif
```

in the game folder itself I have game_x86.exe and game_x64.exe and there I add discord_game_sdk.dll from the folder lib/x86_64 for x64 but from the folder lib/x86 can not add because the names are the same and even if you rename discord_game_sdk_x86.dll will not help, tried to find the source code discord_game_sdk to recompile and add the prefix _x86 and _x64 but I can not find anywhere

please tell me how to make the dll work on two architectures.

I searched the documentation and couldn't find anything

Comment: ***please tell me how to make the dll work on two architectures.*** You can't. It doesn't work that way. 32 and 64 bit are incompatible with each other.

Comment: Do you really need 32-bit? Don't think there's been any 32-bit x86 processors made for quite a while

Comment: drescherjm, There are two versions geme_x32.exe and geme_x64.exe 
geme_x32.exe works on Windows x32
geme_x64.exe it works on Windows x64